# how to insert multiple data from looped table?

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

I want to insert multiple records from a looped table. Each row have hidden inputs.

I will `POST` the total number of rows for the table which will be used in the loop condition.

Here is my view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowcount">//total row of the table
<table class="table" id="ctable" style="border:0;">
            <?php
                foreach ($row12 as $row12) {
                echo"<tr>
                    <td style='vertical-align:midle; width:175px; border:0; padding-right:20px;' align='right' ><b>".$row12->mapel_un."</b></td>
                    <td style='border:0;'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id_peserta' value='$row13->id_peserta'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_un' value='$row12->id_un'>
                        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='nilai' value='$nilai' />
                    </td>
                </tr>";
                }
            ?>
    </table>
```

Here is my model:

```
function simpan_nilai(){
    $jumlah = $this->input->post('rowcount');
    $x=1;
    while($x<=$jumlah){
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO nilai SET
                      id_peserta = '".$this->input->post('id_peserta')."',
                      id_un = '".$this->input->post('id_un')."',
                      nilai = '".$this->input->post('nilai')."' ");
      $x++;
    }
    return "info-Data berhasil disimpan ...";
  }
```

I've only been able to insert the last row of data. For example, if the data is like (001, 1, 100), (001, 2, 90), (001, 3, 95), only the last row of record is inserted into the database i.e. (001, 3, 95).

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your hidden input `name` are the same, and is being looped? Can you try to append a counter after each of the `name`s? It should look like `id_peserta1` for the first row, `id_peserta2` for the second row, etc.

Comment: `function simpan nilai()` ? there is a space in function name?

Comment: @Raptor oh sorry typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closed.

i already fix my problem.

thanks to all who helped me

View:

```
<input type='text' name='rowcount'>
<table class="table" id="ctable" style="border:0;">
   <?php
       foreach ($row12 as $row12) {
          echo"<tr>
                 <td style='vertical-align:midle; width:175px; border:0; padding-right:20px;' align='right' ><b>".$row12->mapel_un."</b></td>
                    <td style='border:0;'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id_peserta' value='$row13->id_peserta'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_un$row12->id_un' value='$row12->id_un'>
                        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='nilai$row12->id_un' value='$nilai' />
                 </td>
               </tr>";
       }
   ?>
</table>
```

Model:

```
function simpan_nilai(){
    $jumlah = $this->input->post('rowcount');
    $x=1;
    while($x<=$jumlah){
      $nilai = 'nilai' . $x;
      $id_un = 'id_un' . $x;
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO nilai SET
                      id_peserta = '".$this->input->post('id_peserta')."',
                      id_un = '".$this->input->post($id_un)."',
                      nilai = '".$this->input->post($nilai)."' ");
      $x++;
    }
    return "info-Data berhasil disimpan ...";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have multiple hidden inputs of the same name `id_peserta`. In your PHP codes, the only input that is received is the last input of the same name.

You can try to append a count after each of your input `name` to make it unique.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowcount"> <!-- total row of the table -->
<table class="table" id="ctable" style="border:0;">
        <?php
            $count = 1; // You can start from zero. Either works.
            foreach ($row12 as $row12) {
                echo "<tr>
                    <td style='vertical-align:midle; width:175px; border:0; padding-right:20px;' align='right' ><b>".$row12->mapel_un."</b></td>
                    <td style='border:0;'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_peserta{$count}' value='$row13->id_peserta'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_un{$count}' value='$row12->id_un'>
                        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='nilai{$count}' value='$nilai' />
                    </td>
                </tr>";
                $count++;
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

And for your PHP codes.

```
function simpan nilai(){
    $jumlah = $this->input->post('rowcount');
    $x=1;
    while($x<=$jumlah){
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO nilai SET
                  id_peserta = '".$this->input->post('id_peserta' + $x)."',
                  id_un = '".$this->input->post('id_un' + $x)."',
                  nilai = '".$this->input->post('nilai' + $x)."' ");
      $x++;
    }
    return "info-Data berhasil disimpan ...";
}
```

Comment: i already try it, and the record result is the id_peserta is null and 0 for id_un and nilai. sorry my english is not good enough

Comment: @Yoshioka Did you also add the `+ $x` within each of your `$this->input->post('id_peserta' + $x)`?